# Java Spring Adding or removing @Component at runtime is possible?

Tags: java, spring, runtime

I have something like this.

```
@Component public class JohnStephen
@Component public class Guadalupe
@Component public class CristianOrtiz
@Component public class CristinaCuellar
/*AND SO ON*/
```

All the profiles are creating all the beans because all the beans can be used on each environment.

I have over 1000 beans created, right? but I did realize that I need just one on each application startup is required I mean I know which of them is required and I can pass that info on the JVM vm_options something like this.

```
vm-options beanToCreate=CristianOrtiz
```

On this info I would like that **CristianOrtiz** only is set as a bean and not the others can this be done in any way in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use spring profiles to switch these on and of at startup but not at runtime.

Annotate each of these Components with `@Profile("profileName")` and activate them with `-Dspring.profiles.active=profileName` as a commandline parameter.

Further reading: 
- a nice primer on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: I think the number of profiles is only limited by the number of profile names and usecases you can think of. Multiple active profiles can be added as comma separated list to the command line.